# How to get autoClosingPairs for current document in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to get `autoClosingPairs` value that is defined via `language-configuration.json` for each language.

```json
{
    "comments": {
        "lineComment": "//",
        "blockComment": [ "/*", "*/" ]
    },
    "brackets": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ],
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        { "open": "{", "close": "}" },
        { "open": "[", "close": "]" },
        { "open": "(", "close": ")" },
        { "open": "'", "close": "'", "notIn": ["string", "comment"] },
        { "open": "\"", "close": "\"", "notIn": ["string"] },
        { "open": "`", "close": "`", "notIn": ["string", "comment"] },
        { "open": "/**", "close": " */", "notIn": ["string"] }
    ],
    "autoCloseBefore": ";:.,=}])>` \n\t",
    "surroundingPairs": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"],
        ["'", "'"],
        ["\"", "\""],
        ["`", "`"]
    ],
    "folding": {
        "markers": {
            "start": "^\\s*//\\s*#?region\\b",
            "end": "^\\s*//\\s*#?endregion\\b"
        }
    },
    "wordPattern": "(-?\\d*\\.\\d\\w*)|([^\\`\\~\\!\\@\\#\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\=\\+\\[\\{\\]\\}\\\\\\|\\;\\:\\'\\\"\\,\\.\\<\\>\\/\\?\\s]+)",
    "indentationRules": {
        "increaseIndentPattern": "^((?!.*?\\/\\*).*\\*\/)?\\s*[\\}\\]].*$",
        "decreaseIndentPattern": "^((?!\\/\\/).)*(\\{[^}\"'`]*|\\([^)\"'`]*|\\[[^\\]\"'`]*)$"
    }
}
```

Closes thing I put together `workspace.getConfiguration(languageId);` and `extensions.getExtension('vscode.typescript-language-features')` but neither has autoClosingPairs value. Read through API docs but could not find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no API to get language configuration values like `autoClosingPairs` yet, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2871, on the Backlog.

But in that issue, there is a workaround posted:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// in some function or `activate`

const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const documentLanguageId = editor.document.languageId;
var langConfigFilepath = null;
for (const _ext of vscode.extensions.all) {
  // All vscode default extensions ids starts with "vscode."
  if (
    _ext.id.startsWith("vscode.") &&
    _ext.packageJSON.contributes &&
    _ext.packageJSON.contributes.languages
  ) {
    // Find language data from "packageJSON.contributes.languages" for the 
    // current file's languageId (or just use them all and don't filter here
    const packageLangData = _ext.packageJSON.contributes.languages.find(
      _packageLangData => (_packageLangData.id === documentLanguageId)
    );
    // If found, get the absolute config file path
    if (!!packageLangData) {
      langConfigFilepath = path.join(
        _ext.extensionPath,
        packageLangData.configuration
      );
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Validate config file existence
if (!!langConfigFilepath && fs.existsSync(langConfigFilepath)) {
    let langConfig = require(langConfigFilepath);
    let aCPs = langConfig.autoClosingPairs; // if you prefer/can use this route

    // or use this
    let aCPs2 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(langConfigFilepath).toString()).autoClosingPairs;
}
```

with slight modifications by me for javascript and `autoClosingPairs` usage in the last `if` body.

Thanks to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2871#issuecomment-338364014

As written, it gets the language configuration file for the `activeTextEditor`.  You could change it to loop your your desired `documentLanguageId`'s.